# How to: background-size: 100% auto, background-attachment: scroll

Tags: css, firefox, background

Firefox has a curious bug relating to background-attachment and background-size.  I call it a bug, I suspect it isn't, but this renders the way I think it should in the other major browsers (emphasis on I think).  The desired effect is to size a vertically repeating background to 100% width while maintaining image proportion.

Here's my original CSS, in this version, the background won't render at all for firefox (even with firefox specific background tags).

```
body {
    background: #000 url('../background.jpg') left top repeat-y;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Changing `background-attachment: scroll;` to `background-attachment: fixed;` causes the background to render, but the "floating background" behavior is not desired.

**[UPDATE]**

Removing background position causes the image to render correctly again.

e.g.

```
body {
    background: #000 url('../background.jpg') repeat-y;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

This is actually a problematic fix because my position values were actually 'left 113px'. I can fix this by applying the background to a wrapping div below the site header instead of the body element, but the fact remains that Firefox has trouble rendering background images with background-size: 100% auto; when position values are used and attachment is scroll.

**[UPDATE 2]**

I realize the bug only shows up when an additional piece of CSS is present.  That's not to say the additional piece of CSS was at fault (it isn't), it's to say that this Firefox specific rendering bug is somehow caused by it.

The additional CSS (used for creating layouts with flexible 100% height)

```
html {  width: 100%;    height: 100%;   position: absolute; }
```

And the complete body CSS to go with to replicate the bug

```
body  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #000 url('image.jpg') top left repeat-y;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

**[SOLUTION]**
I solved my problem by creating an additional wrapped div immediately within the body and attaching the background there without specifying position properties.

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000 url('image.jpg') repeat-y;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

But because I now have an additional wrapper anyway, I can go ahead and remove the position, height, and width attributes from `html`, rendering the bug moot and allowing me to set the position of the background as well.

Comment: scroll is already the default. you don't need to put it.

Comment: yes, but not relevant to the behavior.

Comment: i have tried this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment changed it to scroll and works fine in firefox. perhaps something else is wrong with your code

Comment: also this works exactly the same in chrome and firefox http://jsfiddle.net/8CkpB/

Comment: actually, I duplicated the bug rapidly on the w3schools site.  Incidentally this also led to a fix, albeit an 'incorrect' one, I'll update the question.

Comment: also, from the beginning Chrome, IE, and Safari worked correctly, only firefox has this issue, and it seems to be in the interplay of attachment, size, and position properties.

Comment: Can you link to a page showing the problem?  I just tried this, but it seems to work fine....

Comment: Here's a page with the problem http://jthoburn.com/CSSbugdemo.html

Comment: Please note, I've solved how to correct for the CSS bug, but I'm now convinced that this is indeed a firefox specific bug. The reason it doesn't show up on jsfiddle or w3schools is because of the frames used for rendering the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating an additional wrapped div immediately within the body and attaching the background there without specifying position properties.

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000 url('image.jpg') repeat-y;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

But because I now have an additional wrapper anyway, I can go ahead and remove the position, height, and width attributes from html, rendering the bug moot and allowing me to set the position of the background as well. (see UPDATE 2 in my original question)