# CSS/PHP - Background image moving behind content and going off the screen

Tags: php, html, css

The issue is a bit problematic to create a fiddle but I found a template that has a similar problem: http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=StudioBlue

The issue is the following: there's a wrapper that has all the content inside of it and a background image positioned at the top center with no-repeat. Everything looks fine, until you resize the window until the window size is smaller than the content/wrapper size.

At this point everything still looks fine as the left edge of the content is aligned with the left side of the browser and you get a scroll bar at the bottom. However, if you scroll to the right you'll see that the background image (since it's centered), actually moved to the left and is now partially of the screen, leaving some blank space to the right. Any idea how I can trick the background image to stay on the screen instead of going off the left side when the window size becomes too small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could probably either set the center value to 50% and see what that does (probably nothing different) or you could use media queries for smaller screen sizes. The example you've shown does not have a center position, just a top. Let me know if I understood correctly or what occours! :)

```
background: gray url(img.jpg) 50% top;
```

or

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    body {

         background: gray url(img.jpg) left top;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just setting the position to center doesn't work, but using media queries should. (But it won't work on older browsers.)

Comment: Thank you! The media query is a good idea and it works beautifully. I was hoping to find a better and more robust trick but that will do too!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the image is being centered relative to the width of the window when it needs to be centered relative to the scroll width. To fix that, you can create another div at the top of your html to have the background image:

```
#image-div {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000 url('image.jpg') no-repeat center top;
}
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15792723/1721527